# Java CardLayout .show() not showing

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I use `.show()` before a "blocking" code like a while loop. But even though the .show gets called, the UI doesn't actually show the called panel.

Here is the code that shows the issue:
(WARNING: This code contains a while true loop.)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class CardTest extends JFrame{
public CardTest() {
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout(0,0);
    getContentPane().setLayout(cl);

    JPanel panelA = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panelA, "PanelA");

    JLabel lblPanelA = new JLabel("Panel A");
    panelA.add(lblPanelA);

    JButton btnSwitchToPanel = new JButton("Switch to Panel B");
    panelA.add(btnSwitchToPanel);

    JPanel panelB = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panelB, "PanelB");

    JLabel lblPanelB = new JLabel("Panel B");
    panelB.add(lblPanelB);

    btnSwitchToPanel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            cl.show(getContentPane(), "PanelB");
            getContentPane().revalidate();

            // Here is the problem. Even though cl.show is called first, 
            // it still doesn't show, before the while loop has terminated.
            int i = 0;
            while(i < 1000000){
                i++;
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    });

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new CardTest();
}
}
```

If you are wondering, I need this for a downloader, where the while true loop (to download a file) is called after pressing a button in the first panel. The second panel contains the progress bar. But the progress panel never gets displayed even though the .show function is called before the download code.

**UPDATE**

I do know that putting the loop into a new thread, solves the draw problem, but it also introduces other problems, because I rely on sequential execution of functions after the loop(download file(loop), Unzipp file, move those files...).

The best solution would be to find a way to allow the .show() call to actually take the time to switch panes before continuing with the loop.

Comment: What you need is something like this: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/ProgressBarForDataFetching.java the way I built this, the ProgressBar essentially registers a listener for more data being loaded, updates the progress when more data has been fetched, and then calls repaint so the UI thread can repaint it to show more progress. You can either use this class in your code, or use it as an example of how to achieve what you are trying to do

Comment: `because I rely on sequential execution of functions after the loop` - so put all that code in the Thread as well. Copying of files has nothing to do with the GUI. Or if you are updating the GUI with a message for each file copied then the code needs to execute on the EDT. That is why I suggested the SwingWorker because you can publish results as they become available.

Comment: @camickr That's what I ended up doing. I just wanted to avoid having some parts inside a separate thread, since they all belong into one sequence. But the "SwingWorker" is actually a good idea. I was not aware of the capabilities of it. I could use the callback to continue executing the next function and preserve the sequence, but in the end I decided it was too much wok and I used the "drop the following part of the sequence in a new thread" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are doing work on the EventDispatchingThread. This Thread is also responsible for actually drawing the GUI.

You have no other choice than doing your work in another thread.

E.g.: (Quick + Dirty)

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (...) {...}
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: Putting the loop in a separate thread does work, but breaks up other code that is dependent on the return of the loop (Like unzipping after the file is downloaded). I was hoping for a solution, that can maybe wait that millisecond until the draw is ready to continue going into the loop.

Comment: @Haeri You don't have any other options here. Running code on the EDT will prevent your UI from working correctly. This is how it's done in Java. All the answers provided are correct on this regard. You must adapt the rest of your code base to work with the download being performed in a second thread, rather than trying to force Java to do something it's not supposed to do just because that's how you want to code it.

Answer (score 3):

> I use .show() before a "blocking" code like a while loop. But even though the .show gets called, the UI doesn't actually show the called panel.

Yes, because you are "blocking" the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) which is responsible for repainting the GUI. So the GUI can't repaint itself until the code finishes executing.

You need to create a separate Thread to executing the long running task so you don't block the EDT. One way to do this is to use a `SwingWorker`. The SwingWorker will create the Thread for you and will notify you when the task is complete so you can update the GUI.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and a working example.

Answer (score 2):

This is because redrawing the UI is done in the same thread as event processing and doesn't happen until after the event processing has completed (i.e., all event handling methods have returned).

Best thing to do is move that "blocking" code into a runnable and execute it in a worker thread.